# How to disable google chrome cross domain security

Tags: google-chrome, cross-domain, xmlhttprequest-level2

What's the command to disable the cross domain security in Google Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: Ths chromuim command doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is the command that worked for me for google chrome in ubuntu.

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security
```